# How to extract the Wald p-value from a specific set of linear models with nested data

Tags: tidymodels, broom

This is a 'many models' problem.

I have a set of 16 binary candidate variables. I want to see the 'contribution' of each to a set of outcome variables (n=15), where the other covariates change depending on the candidate to be used.

```
Candidates = c("C1","C2",...)
covariates = c("age","sex"...)
outcomes = c("Cancer","Heart disease",...)
```

First I nested the data by outcome:

`ndat <- data |> group_by(outcome) |> nest()`

The model to be used for each candidate is written like this...

```
lm(value ~ C1 + age + sex, data = df)}

model2 = function(df){
lm(value ~ C2 + sex + ethnicity, data = df)}
```

I then apply each model to the nested data like this:

```
ndat <- ndat |>
mutate(m1 = map(data, model1),
m2 = map(data, model2),
...
)
```

ndat is now a grouped tibble, the first column is a vector of the outcomes.  Each column is then a model (model1, model2 etc), and the elements in each of these columns are lists for the linear models for each outcome.

What I need is to now extract the Wald p-value of the candidate variable from each model.  In each column the candidate is different, and each column is a list of lists (I think).  How can I do this cleanly?

I've tried using `broom::glance` but this returns the overall model metrics, p-values etc. I've also tried all manner of subscripting the ndat tibble, and although I can extract a single Wald value for a candidate in the first model with `summary(ndat$model1[[1]])$coefficients[,4][[1]]`, I can't scale this up to apply to all the models in all the model columns.

What I'm hoping for, is for each ndat model column to turn into a vector of the p-value of the candidate variable for that model, on the row corresponding to the correct outcome.

Here's a reprex using mtcars.

```r
data <- mtcars |>
  mutate(c1  = rbinom(nrow(mtcars),prob=0.05, size = 1),
         c2 = rbinom(nrow(mtcars), prob = 0.1, size =1),
         c3 = rbinom(nrow(mtcars), prob = 0.5, size = 1))
#> Error in mutate(mtcars, c1 = rbinom(nrow(mtcars), prob = 0.05, size = 1), : could not find function "mutate"


candidates <- c("c1","c2","c3")
covars <- c("disp","hp","drat","wt")
outcomes <- c("mpg","qsec")

outcome_cols <- names(data)[names(data) %in% outcomes]

dat_long <- data |>
  pivot_longer(cols=all_of(outcome_cols), names_to = "outcome", values_to = "value")
#> Error in pivot_longer(data, cols = all_of(outcome_cols), names_to = "outcome", : could not find function "pivot_longer"

dat_n <- dat_long |>
  group_by(cyl) |>
  nest()
#> Error in nest(group_by(dat_long, cyl)): could not find function "nest"

c_models <- c("c1_mod","c2_mod","c3_mod")

c1_mod <- function(df){
  lm(value ~ c1 + disp + hp, data = df)
}

c2_mod <- function(df){
  lm(value ~ c2 + disp + drat, data = df)
}

c3_mod <- function(df){
  lm(value ~ c3 + drat + wt, data = df)
}

dat_n <- dat_n |>
  mutate(c1 = map(data, c1_mod),
         c2 = map(data, c2_mod),
         c3 = map(data, c3_mod))
#> Error in mutate(dat_n, c1 = map(data, c1_mod), c2 = map(data, c2_mod), : could not find function "mutate"

#this works for 1 model
glancec1 <- dat_n |>
  mutate(glance = map(c1, broom::glance)) |>
  unnest(glance) |>
  select(cyl, BIC, adj.r.squared) |>
  mutate(model = "c1")
#> Error in mutate(select(unnest(mutate(dat_n, glance = map(c1, broom::glance)), : could not find function "mutate"

#but this does not (when trying to extend the above for all the models)

glances <- data.frame()


for (i in c_models) {
  print(i)
  glance <- dat_n |>
    mutate(glance = map(i, broom::glance)) |>
    unnest(glance) |>
    select(cyl, BIC, adj.r.squared) |>
    mutate(model = as.character(i))
  
  glances <- bind_rows(glances, glance)
}
#> [1] "c1_mod"
#> Error in mutate(select(unnest(mutate(dat_n, glance = map(i, broom::glance)), : could not find function "mutate"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Claire, welcome to StackOverflow. This problem is very specific, so the best way for us to help you is for you to provide a minimum reproducible example. That means giving us data and code so we can reproduce what you have on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague stepped in here and gave me a lovely answer, posting for future reference!

````
    dat_n |>
        mutate(glance = map(.data[[cmod]], broom::glance)) |>
        unnest(glance) |>
        select(cyl, BIC, adj.r.squared) |>
        mutate(model = cmod)
}
glancec1 <- glance_fun("c1", dat_n)
c_models <- c("c1","c2","c3")
glances <- bind_rows(map(c_models, glance_fun, dat_n))```
````

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**